# How to smoothen blood vessels image and fill unwanted holes

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-morphology

[image]

I have segmented vessel map from fundus image but it contains many unwanted holes between vessels , 
Can someone please suggest any method to fill holes and to smoothen the image

Comment: This is not trivial. It’s hard to distinguish a hole in a vessel from a hole between two vessels. You need to model the branching structure of the vessel network and use some logic to decide when to join separate regions and when not to.

Answer (score 0):

Use closing = cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

Comment: May be median filter?